# How to send a 3 dimensional array from an HTML form to PHP controller file?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, associative-array

I'm trying to retrieve an array from an HTML form where each row has its own ID (they are numbered), and then within each row, there are 5 different columns that should each have a corresponding value. The form looks like this: [HTML Form](http://i62.tinypic.com/2zolldf.jpg)

I have the code in the template file looking like this:

```
<tbody>
  <?php $trade_row = 0; ?>
  <tr id="trade-row<?php echo $trade_row; ?>">
    <td class="text-left"><input type="text" size="1" name="trades[<?php echo $trade_row; ?>][quantity]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_quantity; ?>" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td class="text-left"><input type="text" size="40" name="trades[<?php echo $trade_row; ?>][name]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td class="text-left"><input type="text" size="30" name="trades[<?php echo $trade_row; ?>][part]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_part; ?>" id="input-part" class="form-control" /></td>
    <td class="text-left"><textarea cols="45" rows="3" name="trades[<?php echo $trade_row; ?>][description]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_description; ?>" id="input-description" class="form-control" /></textarea></td>
    <td class="text-left">
      <select name="trades[<?php echo $trade_row; ?>][condition]" id="input-condition" class="form-control">
        <option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option>
        <option value="1">New</option>
        <option value="2">Used</option>
        <option value="3">Out of Service</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$('#trade-row<?php echo $trade_row; ?>').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I'm using JQuery to generate the extra rows, which is working perfect. The row numbers are being numbered correctly, so I know this is not the issue.

Here is a piece of code from the PHP controller file where I am simply trying to reference the array created from the form for data validation purposes:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['trades'])) {
    foreach($this->request->post['trades'] as $trade) {
        foreach($trade as $info) {
            if (isset($this->error[$trade][$info])) {
                $data['error_trades'][$trade][$info] = $this->error[$trade][$info];
            } else {
                $data['error_trades'][$trade][$info] = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think I am setting up the naming (`name=""`) on the HTML side properly, maybe I am not referencing it correctly on the PHP side, or maybe both. I just need to format it correctly so I can send the data from one end and receive it on the other in order to use the data in my form validation  functions and eventually send it in an email. Thanks!

Comment: i dont know what type of class your `$this` is and whats inside, but have u tried to use the $_POST["trades"] instead? if it holds the n-dims of the array then the class had some errors on multi dim arrays. anywasy, only checking isset for `['trades']` may fires error when no array is given, i would add a check to make sure the var is an array, too

Comment: `$_POST['trades']` is what I would use in my template file, not the controller file. I'm working with Opencart, if this helps any. And this is just a small piece of code, I want to know how to rearrange this piece of code here: `$data['error_trades'][$trade][$info]` or `$data['trades'][$trade][$info]` which I would pass to my mail template file as `$trades[$trade][$info]`.

Comment: sorry if im misunderstood, but you want that to store the content of `$data['error_trades'][$trade][$info]` or `$data['trades'][$trade][$info]` in `$trades[$trade][$info]`? if so then try `$trades = $this->request->post['trades']` and handle it in your template as `$trades`

Comment: Then how do I validate the `$trades` data among other data inside my validation function which is located in my controller file?

Comment: you have to use the vars in foreach as reference and pass it after the validation to the template var, eg `foreach($this->request->post['trades'] as &$trade)` and `foreach($trade as &$info)` - then validate your vars. after that use like above `$trades = $this->request->post['trades']`, if u want to use the $data... too, then add it to $info or $trade, too.